# Executable on a windows platform with python interpreter

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I know that there was py2exe in which once it is run the executable can be run on any windows platform without python Interpreter. But now it being discontinued what are my alternatives for a all windows platform executable with a python interpreter?

I tried pyInstaller in Windows 10 x64 but when I opened it in Windows 7 x64, it should a lot of errors. Is downgrading my python to 3.3 and running py2exe a good idea? Even if I did will py2exe support win 7, 8 and 10 with both x64 and x32 bit ?

I know this was answered before here but there are people giving different opinions and most of the questions were a bit old, where everyone is recommending py2exe for windows which was answered before it was discontinued.

(A one directory converter is recommended for me than a single exe file)

Thanks

Comment: First, you should build the exe on oldest Windows version (building on 32bitWin7 runs on all newer (and 64bit) Windows versions), it's not guaranteed to work 
the other way round. Officially py2exe doesnt support newer Python versions (you could try this fork: (https://github.com/albertosottile/py2exe).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `cx_Freeze 5.0`?

It was recommended by a couple of users around Stack overflow and supposedly the project supports python 3.5 and higher. Unfortunately, I myself cannot assure you that it will work, as I haven't tried using it myself. 
It really depends on how complex your code is and how much `py2exe` unsupported elements it contains.

If it isn't an unsurmountable or very time consuming task, maybe you could adjust the code to be convertable with `py2exe`, because that way the converter often works just fine. I cannot guarantee you that it will work for sure, but converting simpler code worked for me every time.

I hope this helps. Have a great time!